# What counts as a Forest?

Tags: terraria

I'm trying to make homes for my NPCs to make them happy, but my merchant and Zoologist both keep saying they want to be in a forest

Bellow is their current houses 
[image]

I'm quite sure i'm in a forest Biome and there's trees outside of their places and bellow them.

So what do i need to do to make this into a forest to make them happy?

Answer (score 9):

NPCs don't say what biome or neighbours they like, they say what they think of their current biome and neighbours. Your Merchant and Zoologist are mentioning liking the forest *because* they're living in the forest.